# Use Croston model with R hts package

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I think this is similar post to [this post passing forecasting method to hts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670174/passing-different-forecasting-method-to-hierarchical-time-series-forecast-in-r)

The example given there is for MAPE package. Is it possible to use the croston function in the forecast package in a similar way?

I simply tried

```
all_ts <- aggts(bts)
  allf <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = ncol(all_ts))
  for(i in 1:ncol(all_ts)){
       allf[,i] <- croston(all_ts[,i],h = 3)  
  }
```

But that gives me an error saying number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the structure of the object returned by `croston`. It is not a simple vector. The following code is an example that works.

```
library(hts)
nodes <- list(2, c(3, 2))
abc <- ts(5 + matrix(sort(rnorm(500)), ncol = 5, nrow = 100))
bts <- hts(abc, nodes)
all_ts <- aggts(bts)
allf <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = ncol(all_ts))
for(i in 1:ncol(all_ts)){
  allf[,i] <- croston(all_ts[,i],h = 3)$mean
}
y.f <- combinef(allf, bts$nodes)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt respond sir. I think this is what I wanted to know. However when I run this code I will get the same forecasted value for all three time periods. I still couldn't identify what went wrong.

Comment: You wanted Croston's method. That's the way it works.